# Treatment of missing values introduced by padding lagged variables

Tags: regression, time-series, random-forest, missing-data, lags

In the case of a linear regression with lagged independent variables, what are the techniques for dealing with the NA values introduced by padding lagged variables (since t < 0 values do not exist)?

I ask because I'm implementing a random forest with lags and have to decide what to do about these missing values.

Replacing them with 0 seems misguided, but imputing backwards doesn't make much sense either. I suppose I could insert a time mean, or an overall mean for the variable if I have panel data...

Edit 1: Looking around more, SAS lets you choose between replacing NA with a time mean, overall mean, or zero: http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_panel_sect015.htm
Any idea on the costs and benefits of these different approaches?

Comment: I don't think there is a sound way to handle missing values in random forest. I know there are other tree based methods (even CARTs themselves) that can be built with surrogate splits on the predictors (as I understand it you are trying to predict time series with a RF so the lagged variables are your predictors). Another thing that can be interesting is a semi-supervised random forest which I read about sometime ago. Look it up.

Comment: How does a program like Stata deal with these NAs in the case of linear regression? I never thought about this problem in the past because Stata just dealt with it automatically.

Comment: You might think to get rid of cases with NAs, ie keep a window of size $w$ and mine subsequences of size $w$ from the time series. Otherwise, use the way WEKA RandomForest deal with missing values: spreading NAs records to each branch according to their priors. In you case NAs have a meaning (that is you are extracting records from the beginning of the sequence). You might think to modify your code to have ternary splits, where the 3rd split is the one related to records with missing values.

Comment: Stata drops NA's. This is typical of most programs since NA is distinctly from zero.
Ex: If I do not participate in a race, I have an NA for time, that time is non-zero, but it's not any specific number either.